# jQuery :last-child not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Hi I'm trying to use :last-child in IE8 with no result.
An example of what I'm trying to do is

```
jQuery(".menu-item:last-child").addClass("clear-right");
```

This works fine everywhere for me but IE, and suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the code and HTML you're using? then maybe we can help you better.

Comment: we really need to see the html here

Comment: Is it possible that the selector *is* working, but the CSS is not?

Answer (score 5):

Your jQuery code works well, but note, that ie8 throws away whole CSS declaration containing CSS3 `:last-child` selector between other (multiple) selectors. Example :

```
.menu-item:last-child, menu-item.clear-right {
    clear: right;
}
```

will **not** work in ie8, but following **will** work everywhere:

```
.menu-item:last-child {
    clear: right;
}
 menu-item.clear-right {
    clear: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the menu items are `ul li` elements.

```
$(".menu-item li:last-child").addClass("clear-right");
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/PBAas/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
jQuery(".menu-item").children().last().addClass("clear-right");
               // get children->last child
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/PBAas/3/)

Comment: -1: They are not the same thing. :last-child selects all .menu-item that are the last child of its parent. jQuery.last() just gets the last item in jQuery object.

Comment: Still not the same thing. With :last-child, the element itself is the last child of it's parent, you are getting the element's children. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/PBAas/4/